# python2; which python comes with pip>8?

Tags: python, pip

By default, python 2.7.11 comes with pip 7.1.2. We are using chef/cloudify to automatically create virtualenvs and have no control over that process. This means doing a `pip install --upgrade pip` after creating a new virtualenv is not possible. We have plugins that we need Chef to install that require pip>8 (where --trusted-host was added as a capability in requirements.txt).

So my question is, which python2 version can I install that out of the box comes with the latest version of pip, such that newly created venvs have pip>8?

Comment: Well, pip8 was released just a few weeks ago, there has not been any python2.7 release in the last days, so I doubt that you can find a stable python version that ships pip8 out of the box.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but this is a classic "Use Docker" scenario.

Comment: Docker is not an option here. Chef + Cloudify already run inside of Docker and have their version of python. I can upgrade it, but new virtualenvs are based off that python. I upgraded it to 2.7.11, but new virtualenvs still come up old.

Answer (score 0):

If installing Python from Mercurial is an option, then it already includes pip 8.0.0 (https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/65b7eb7dfb64). If you have to wait for a release, it could still take a few months.

This [does not appear to be the only issue you're facing with Chef/Cloudify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279991/python2-pip-parse-requirements-with-trusted-host-and-extra-index-url) - you should consider switching to something that gives your more control over your environment. (If the only thing you can do is putting things in setup.py, that's already a lot since you can write arbitrary Python there.)